# Extract polygons from TIFF file of depth model

Tags: qgis, polygon, geotiff-tiff, navigation

I am trying to create a shapefile of polygons from a TIFF file using QGIS. The TIFF file represents a depth model of Denmark. I want to create the polygons based on a particular depth (-2 meters), which would produce areas where travelling by boat is not possible. I have tried using the raster calculator to filter out said points, which I then polygonize. The problem is that I get an outline within the areas which I think represents land. I want to remove the land and only have the outside polygon representing -2 meters or above. This is a screenshot of after having used the raster calculator followed by a screenshot of an island with the outline mentioned.
[image: After raster calculator]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reclassify by table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table) tool to create a new raster where values <-2.9 or values >-2 (or whatever values you choose) equal No Data (or -9999) and values within your range = 1.  Make sure the resulting output raster is a type integer.

Convert the resulting [raster to a polygon](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html).

Comment: When I perform the reclassification with the rows 
1) -500 < x ≤ -2 → 1
2) -1.9 < x ≤ ∞ → -9999
I get a result that seems to look like what I want, however the polygons seem to come out inverted. I have tried inverting them using the properties field, but when I export it as a shapefile they are still the same regardless. Do you know how I can export the inverted polygons?

Comment: Hi, Lukas.  Comments are not meant to have running dialogs in GIS SE.  Best to post a new question asking about properly setting the table values in a QGIS reclassify by table operation.  Include a screen shot of the tool parameters, a screen shot of the table, and the output you received and why that is a problem.  A well written and documented question will receive answers.  Poorly posted question get closed quickly.