Fill holes in polygon that does not connect with surroundings
I have created a vectorization from a raster of a sea model of Denmark as suggested here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/478370/240539 using QGIS.
I get this vectorization:
I wish to fill the holes in the polygons such that all the white areas inside the polygons that is not connected to the larger white area becomes part of whatever polygon they are inside of. Below I have outlined two of the white holes that I wish to eliminate and make part of the larger polygon.

I also wish to remove inner polygons like this one that does not have the same white coloring. I have tried using the "delete holes" tool which deletes the islands inside of the large white area which is the opposite of what I want. Inverting the polygons doesn't seem to be respected as running the tool with inverted polygons does the exact same. I have also tried using the "geometry by expression" with this suggestion https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/471769/240539 however this creates the same white colored holes as mentioned above in their place instead.


I solved this by identifying the feature composing the large white area and removing all the others.

Please put your comment in an answer, and mark it as "answered" so it is immediately clear to everyone that your question is solved. Possibly it takes some time before you are able to because of spam avoidance measures.

I solved this by identifying the feature composing the large white area and removing all the others.
